# HTML Parser Library For C

Tags: html, c, parsing

I just need a suggestion. I have a program that takes valid html, and saves it to a file, I need a way to parse this html file to retrieve every image documented within that html file. (e.g. /foo/bar.jpg). Is there a html parsing library that I could use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half an answer: There's a *Java* parser called [Tagsoup](http://mercury.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) which will "Just Keep On Truckin'", parsing anything with angle brackets and always producing a valid set of events to the application.

I mention this because I know that the idea *and*, crucially, the name have been adopted by libraries which have the same intention, in other languages.  I can't find a C version right now, but you may have more luck if you try some inventive searches with that starting point (the point is that the application which sits atop the parser doesn't have to care about the horrors in the original source, but can pretend that it was well-formed XML, and do XMLish things to/with it).

**Edit:** oooh, and ... there we go [Taggle](http://www.jezuk.co.uk/cgi-bin/view/arabica/log?id=3591) (C++, but possibly close enough, and that posting suggests that porting it from Java wasn't hard)

Comment: Your answer was very insightful thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If all you need are the .jpg files mentioned, you should get a pretty good result (e.g., few false positives) using just a file reader and regular expression matcher looking for .jpg file-name like strings.

You won't get all the .jpg files even if you have a perfect HTML parser, as some of the file names may be assembled by JavaScript text that you can't possibly interpret, so not being perfect doesn't seem like much of a loss.

Comment: This is a very solid point, thank you, I think I will take this route.

Answer (score 2):

[Gumbo Parser](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser) , by Google.
It's an HTML5 parser in pure C with no dependencies

Answer (score 1):

There is [libXml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/%20libXml2)  . But that may require the file to be XHTML, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I thinh You can use libcurl, I have used it in the past to parse regular expressions in HTML websites to retrieve pictures and e-mail's in a certain deepness. I coul provide you some tips if I find the code.