# extract Location from http socket

Tags: c, string, scanf, strstr

I have the following http reply saved in a local file called source.txt:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved
Connection: close
Content-length: 111
Location: https://11.12.13.14:81/
Content-type: text/html; charset="utf-8"

<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=https://11.12.13.14:81/"></head><body></body></html>
```

and the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXBUFLEN 1024

char* getLocation(char* source)
{
    const char *p1 = strstr(source, "Location:")+10;
    const char *p2 = strstr(p1, "\n");
    size_t len = p2-p1;
    char *res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    strncpy(res, p1, len);
    res[len] = '\0';
    return res;
}

char* getData(char* source)
{
    const char *p1 = strstr(source, "://")+3;
    const char *p2 = strstr(p1, "\n");
    size_t len = p2-p1;
    char *res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    strncpy(res, p1, len);
    res[len] = '\0';
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    char source[MAXBUFLEN];
    char host[100];
    int port;
    FILE *fp = fopen("source.txt", "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        size_t newLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), MAXBUFLEN, fp);
        if (newLen == 0) {
            fputs("Error reading file", stderr);
        } else {
            source[++newLen] = '\0';

//extraction code
            char* line = getLocation(source);
            printf("getLocation result: %s\n", line);
            if (strstr(line, "://"))
            {
                char* res = getData(line);//here is the error
                printf("getData result: %s\n", res);
                if (strstr(res, ":"))
                {
                    sscanf(res, "%[^:]:%d[^/]", host, &port);
                    printf("host: %s | port: %d\n", host, port);
                }
                else
                    printf("delimiter not found\n");
            }
            else
                printf("no link\n");
//
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The program is working good but it's very ugly.

***Is there any way to improve the code to avoid doing so many operations?***

I mean merging somehow those 2 functions getLocation and getData ...

EDIT: my mistake, getData must extract from res not from source

Comment: Consider using a library to help parse that HTML, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064324/html-parser-library-for-c) question for a start.

Comment: I don't want to use any external library.

Comment: This type of question would be better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes, you're right! sorry, but I didn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXBUFLEN 1024

char* getLocation(char* source)
{
    const char *p1 = strstr(source, "Location:")+10;
    const char *p2 = strstr(p1, "\n");
    size_t len = p2-p1;
    char *res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    strncpy(res, p1, len);
    res[len] = '\0';
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    char source[MAXBUFLEN];
    char host[100];
    int port;
    FILE *fp = fopen("source.txt", "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        size_t newLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), MAXBUFLEN, fp);
        if (newLen == 0) {
            fputs("Error reading file", stderr);
        } else {
            source[++newLen] = '\0';

//extraction code
            char* res = getLocation(source);
            printf("getLocation result: %s\n", res);
            res = strstr(res,"://");
            if (res != NULL)
            {
                res = res+3;
                if (strstr(res, ":"))
                {
                    sscanf(res, "%[^:]:%d[^/]", host, &port);
                    printf("host: %s | port: %d\n", host, port);
                }
                else
                    printf("delimiter not found\n");
            }
            else
                printf("no link\n");
//
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be the obvious way:

```
char * getstuff(char * source, char * label) {
    const char *p1 = strstr(source, label) + strlen(label);
    const char *p2 = strstr(p1, "\n");
    size_t len = p2-p1;

    char *res = malloc(len+1);
    if ( res == NULL ) {
        fputs("Couldn't allocate memory.", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strncpy(res, p1, len);
    res[len] = '\0';

    return res;
}

char* getLocation(char* source) {
    return getstuff(source, "Location: ");
}

char* getData(char* source) {
    return getstuff(source, "://");
}
```

or just having `getstuff()` and leaving out `getLocation()` and `getData()` entirely, if you're only going to call each function once.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are working on `linux`,
I have an answer in awk:

```
awk '///:/{print $2}' source.txt
```

will act just like your `getLocation()`

and i suspect `getData()` should actually give you the `html content` ( but your code returns the string same as `getLocation()` but without `http://`). So, here is my `awk` code for getting `html` content.

```
awk '/<html>/{print $0}' source.txt
```

will give you the actual content of the html reply.(of course I assumed no `\n` characters in the content. But can be easily extended).

To integrate this into your code, just do the following:

```
system("command >> op.txt");
```

where `command` refers to the two awk commands I wrote previously. You can then read the output from the file `op.txt`. 30 lines of code to just 2 lines ( + some code to read the `op.txt`). I hope this helps. :) :)

Comment: I know what awk does but this is c coding and has nothing to do with linux commands.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question